# how to run a forloop in nested lists so that the loop keeps entering each nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to remove empty list from a list no matter how deep they are nested

example `a = [2, 3, [[[[[]]]]], [[4, []]] , 5, 6, [], [], []]`

desired answer

```
b = [2, 3, [[4]] , 5, 6 ]
```

so far I have

```
def delete_empty_list(x):
   b = [x for x in a if x != []]    
   return(b)
```

which gives me

```
b = [2, 3, [[[[[]]]]], [[4, []]], 5, 6]
```

I don't know how to loop inside nested items in a list. Also the items can be nested however deep my function should still work.

Comment: Study divide and conquer algorithms like recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion:

```
def remove(lst):
    result = []
    for e in lst:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            l = remove(e)
            if l:
                result.append(l)
        else:
            result.append(e)
    return result


a = [2, 3, [[[[[]]]]], [[4, []]], 5, 6, [], [], []]

print(remove(a))
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, [[4]], 5, 6]
```

The idea is to check if the element is a list, then call remove recursively on the element if the result is not empty add it. In the case of normal elements (not list) just add them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with `filter`:

```
a = [2, 3, [[[[[]]]]], [[4, []]] , 5, 6, [], [], []] 
def _filter(d):
  r = [c if not isinstance(c, list) else _filter(c) for c in d if c != []]
  return list(filter(lambda x:x != [], r))

print(_filter(a))
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, [[4]], 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
a = [2, 3, [[[[[]]]]], [[4, []]] , 5, 6, [], [], []]

def filter_function(e):
    if isinstance(e, list):
        return filter(None, map(filter_function, e))
    elif e != []:
        return e

print filter_function(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following recursive function with list comprehension:

```
def f(a):
    return [i for l in a for i in [f(l) if isinstance(l, list) else l] if i != []]
```

so that:

```
f([2, 3, [[[[[]]]]], [[4, []]] , 5, 6, [], [], []])
```

returns:

```
[2, 3, [[4]], 5, 6]
```